# TTTableViewCell height problem - Three20

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, three20

I am trying to subclass TTTableViewCell in my Three20 app, and I would like to change the height of the cell.  However, I am having major issues.

I am using `self.variableHeightRows = YES`; in the class which call my TTTableViewCell class.

Does anyone have any idea how to change the height of the cell?  The doc for this is almost nil.

Many thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 1):

Override this method in your subclass of TTTableViewCell:

```
+ (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView rowHeightForObject:(id)object {
    return 0; // Your value here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used TTTableViewCell, however for a regular cell that is contained within a UITableView in the UITableViewDelegate you can implement the method

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: Unfortunately it is different for TTTableViewCell :(

Comment: ahh yes i figured, as i have looked at the api a tad...but was hoping to give you some ideas as to what might change it heh. good luck.